# Putting a "-" instead of a "+" breaks the system of equations, why?

Tags: equations

This code works:

```
\[
    \syslineskipcoeff{1}
h(n) = \systeme*{\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}} \;\text{se}\:n> 0,
\\,
0 \;\; \text{se} \; n = 0,
-\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}} \;\text{se}\:n<0}\]
```

While this one doesn't:

```
\[
    \syslineskipcoeff{1}
h(n) = \systeme*{\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}} \;\text{se}\:n> 0,
\\,
0 \;\; \text{se} \; n = 0,
-\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}} \;\text{se}\:n<0}\]
```

Latex tells me "Missing = inserted for \ifnum". What can I do to fix it??

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full but minimal self contained example that others can copy and test as is. For example which package provides `\systeme`?

Comment: With `\usepackage{systeme}`  in the preamble (amsart documentclass) I get the same error in both cases, namely `L'indice n'est pas un nombre entier !.`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this case, as pointed out in another comment, it seems like a particular package is causing the issue so you can see why its important to include your preamble.

Comment: You don't want `\systeme`, but `cases`